# Sending a POST with PHP doesn't work with curl or file_get_contents, just normal bash CURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm having some serious problems sending a POST. Using curl on the shell, my POST works perfectly. However, when using PHP curl, or file_get_contents, it doesn't work at all. I get a 500 error from the webserver.

```
curl -X POST -H"Content-Type:application/xml" "http://myserver:8080/createItem?name=NewItem" --user root:123456 --data-binary @template.xml
```

And this:

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1, 
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type:application/xml"),
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://myserver:8080/createItem?name=" . rawurlencode("NewItem"), 
    CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1, 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
    CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => 1, 
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 20, 
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "root:123456",
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => file_get_contents("template.xml"),
);

$post = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt_array($post, $options); 
if(!$result = curl_exec($post)) { 
    trigger_error(curl_error($post)); 
} 

curl_close($post);
```

And this:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => sprintf("Authorization: Basic %s\r\n", base64_encode('root:123456')) . "Content-Type:application/xml",
        'timeout' => 20,
        'content' => file_get_contents("template.xml"),
    ),
));
$ret = file_get_contents("http://myserver:8080/createItem?name=" . rawurlencode("NewItem"), false, $context);
```

Am i doing something absurd here and i'm not seeing? I don't see a reason for the normal curl from the shell to work perfectly, but not the PHP implementations.

Comment: Please check the error log of Apache and probably post details. 500 should seldom occur. In other words, this is likely to be an uncommon problem. What request actually is received by the server?

Comment: What is the content of template.xml?  Is it a string in `name=value` format?

Comment: It's not Apache, it's Winstone. The content of template.xml is XML, which should be transmitted as binary data, no urlencoded.

Comment: Could you post error log entries?

Comment: Just a Java stack trace, NullPointerException. I believe that it's failing because PHP is not able to send the contents of template.xml through the POST. Otherwise, there would be no reason for the normal curl version to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Hum... I don't think that's possible with `php/curl`, but try:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('@template.xml'),
```

Comment: I get a Notice: Operation timed out after 20001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Comment: @vinnylinux: Yeah, I suspected something weird would happen. Are you able to change your `createItem` script to receive the file in a named parameter? Something like /`createItem?name=NewItem&xml=FILE`? The `xml` argument would still be POST'ed of course.

Comment: Nope... the target server is a Jenkins instance. The only way is to send the XML inside the request. I wish i could do a GET, but no. :(

Comment: @vinnylinux: Then I suppose your only option is to see how the CURL CLI is sending the request and mimic the same using raw sockets. =\

Answer (score 0):

It IS possible, take a look at this:
    `// same as <input type="file" name="file_box">

    $post = array(

        "file_box"=>"@/path/to/myfile.jpg",

    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);`

Source: http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html

Comment: Yes, but there is no `file_box` in the CURL CLI example the OP provided, that's why I doubt it's possible since PHP/curl only allows you to upload files if you prefix the array value with `@`. The question is, what should the array key be.

Comment: Just change it whatever to whatever the upload POST name is called.

Comment: AFAIK, the HTTP/1.1 spec allows you to POST whatever without specifying the "POST name", however the CURL PHP extension does not.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, headers here

```
'header'  => sprintf("Authorization: Basic %s\r\n", base64_encode('root:123456')) 
           . "Content-Type:application/xml",
```

should end with \r\n [see [example 1 here]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)

```
'header'  => sprintf( "Authorization: Basic %s\r\n", base64_encode('root:123456')) 
           . "Content-Type: application/xml\r\n",
```

Comment: Clever, but that's not it. :(